Use scanf() to read \n in a loop?
I must use scanf() to read each 2-digit hexadecimal value. Each 2-digit
hexadecimal number will be separated by a single space and a ‘\n’ character (rather
than a space after the number) will indicate that the message is complete. Your program should scan through every value until either you have read in maxium number of inputs or you have reached to the end of line. The maxium number of inputs are 5.
For example, a valid input might be: 00 4A 12 BB 43 88
Another valid input will be: AA BB 33 12(\n)
If i have my number of inputs greater than or equal to MAX_CHAR_LENGTH, it will work fine. However, it seems to not able to work when the number of inputs are smaller than that. Is there a way to detect whether curr_hex is \n or not so I could break out?
This is what I had for my program
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_CHAR_LENGTH 5
int main() {

    unsigned int curr_hex;
    
    printf("enter hex values: " ); // prompt user to enter hex values
    
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR_LENGTH && !(curr_hex == '\n'); i++) { 
    scanf("%x", &curr_hex);
    printf("Read hex: 0x%02X\n", curr_hex);
    }
    return 0;
}


Add on to it, if I supply anything less than 5 values, let's say AA BB CC DD only, then this program will just keep waiting for me until I have enter something else in. It wouldn't quit no matter how many times I have pressed enter

Edit your question with additional data and delete the comment.

Always check the return value of scanf() otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized variables. curr_hex is not initialized when the loop starts so you have undefined behavior.

The problem description is ambiguous and/or doesn't match input provided.  You said hex number is separated by space and \n but data shows space and only newline when done.  You also said you should read at most 5 numbers but your first example is 6 so is that invalid input, or valid and you just read 5 of the 6 numbers?  I suggest you show some sample input and expected output.

The format string %x will silent convert 1 to 0x01 so is that ok or a failure?

What if a non-hex digit is entered like 'z'?

scanf can only take you so far. At some point you'll need to employ tools like fgets, strtok and sscanf.

Note: unsigned int curr_hex; The uninitialised value of this variable is tested before the loop body is started... This may not work next Tuesday afternoon...

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and you might want to read some pages of the [help], too. -- OT: !(curr_hex == '\n') adds mental load, better use curr_hex != '\n'. However, you will not read the end-of-line in this way into curr_hex.

If you need line-by-line processing, use fgets() and parse the read line with sscanf() (if that counts).

Please provide examples of invalid input. Note scanf to skip white characters (including \n so you can have many surprises in case of corner cases.

You can read individual characters with %c or %[ but be aware that both the terminal line discipline and the stdin buffering scheme will prevent any input from reaching the program until a newline is entered when the user hits the Enter key.
Here is a modified version:
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_CHAR_LENGTH 5

int main(void) {
    unsigned int curr_hex;
    char c;
    
    printf("enter hex values: " ); // prompt user to enter hex values
    
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR_LENGTH; i++) { 
        if (scanf("%x%c", &curr_hex, &c) != 2) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Read hex: 0x%02X\n", curr_hex);
        if (c == '\n')
            break;
        if (c != ' ') {
            printf("invalid separator: %c\n", c);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

The above program will accept hex values with more than 2 digits, including values above 255. You can avoid this with this alternate approach:
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_CHAR_LENGTH 5

int main(void) {
    unsigned int curr_hex;
    char sep[2];
    
    printf("enter hex values: " ); // prompt user to enter hex values
    
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR_LENGTH; i++) { 
        // read at most 2 hex digits followed by either a space or a newline
        if (scanf("%2x%1[ \n]", &curr_hex, sep) != 2) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Read hex: 0x%02X\n", curr_hex);
        if (*sep == '\n')
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

The above program will still accept hex values with a single digit. To ensure exactly 2 digits were entered, you can use %n to get the number of characters read and check the length:
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_CHAR_LENGTH 5

int main(void) {
    unsigned int curr_hex;
    int n;
    char sep[2];
    
    printf("enter hex values: " ); // prompt user to enter hex values
    
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR_LENGTH; i++) { 
        // read at most 2 hex digits followed by either a space or a newline
        if (scanf("%2x%n%1[ \n]", &curr_hex, &n, sep) != 2 || n != 2) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Read hex: 0x%02X\n", curr_hex);
        if (*sep == '\n')
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

The problem with scanf is error recovery: it is cumbersome to handle invalid input gracefully.  A better solution is to read input one line at a time with fgets() and parse it with sscanf or other functions.

%2x will still skip leading whitespace so "  aa " will  mess up %n;  %1*[ \n] to suppress the sep as you don't use it?  Didn't think of  %n.  Neat.

@AllanWind: you are correct,  0 will be accepted erroneously. I use sep to check for end of input (instead of c).

Err... reading a line oriented input with scanf is masochism (or sadism from your teacher if this is an assignment). The blessed way would be to first read the line with fgets and then scan it with strtol.
Something like:
char line[32];
if (NULL == fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {       // read a full line
    ...                                 // handle the read error
}
if (strlen(line) == sizeof(line) -1) {  // a too long line?
    ...                                 // handle the error condition
}
char *start = line;                     // search for a number starting at start
char *end;                              // define an end pointer
for (;;) {
    int val = strtol(start, &end, 16);  // read an hexa value
    if (end == start) {                 // nothing more to read?
        break;                          // exit the loop
    }
    printf("Read hex: 0x%02X\n", val);
    start = end;                        // continue past the got value
}
printf("\n");


If you are required to use scanf, you will have to control whether the character following the hexa value is a '\n'.
Something like:
for(;;) {
    int val;
    char c;
    if (1 != scanf("%x", &val)) {             // try to read an hex value
        ...                                   // handle the read error
        break;
    }
    if (1 != scanf("%c", &c)) {
        ...                                   // handle the read error
        break;
    }
    if (c == '\n') break;                     // got the newline!
    printf("Read hex: 0x%02X\n", val);
}

Yet this is not immune to blank characters before the end of line, so this is a very fragile code.
The robust way would be to use fgetc and ungetc:
for(;;) {
    int val;
    int c;
    if (1 != scanf("%x", &val)) {             // try to read an hex value
        ...                                   // handle the read error
        break;
    }
    do {
        c = fgetc(stdin);                     // BEWARE: getc returns an int!
        if (c == EOF) {                       // because EOF is an int constant
            ...                               // handle the read error
            break;
    } while (isblank(c));                     // will skip any space or tab
    if ((c == '\n') || (c == EOF) break;      // got the newline or an error
    ungetc(c, stdin);                         // else put c back into the stream
    printf("Read hex: 0x%02X\n", val);
}
printf("\n");


But beware: none of the above code has been tested: typos can be expected...
